# ForLoop on tar files

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to write a script that checks for the disk space and then act based on the used percentage of the disk. In the event that the threshold is exceeded, I want to be able to delete some files from a dailybackup directory. However I have found it challenging iterating through the contents (tar files) of that directory. Any ideas on how I could do that? Below is how the script looks at the moment;

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Drive cleanup

threshold='70'

currentDate=$(date +%F | sed 's/-//g')

currentDateClip=$(date +%F | sed 's/-//g' | cut -c 1-4)

used=$(df -h | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/%//g' | head -3 | tail -1)

dir='~/scripts/dailybackup/*.sheldns.*'

if [ $used -ge $threshold ]

then

    for FILE in $dir

    local secondArg=$((basename $FILE) | cut -c 1-4)
    do
        if [ (expr currentDate - secondArg) -gt '400' ]
        then
            echo "We are good to go"
        else
            :
    done
else
    :
fi
```

Comment: So `$dir` is full of tar files?

Comment: What is `*.sheldns.*`?  Is that a directory or a string within the files?

Comment: Will you really have files greater than 400 years old?

Comment: Rather than a messy `df -h | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/%//g' | head -3 | tail -1`, why not a nice clean(er) `df --output="pcent" / | tr -d "A-Za-z% \n"`?  (naturally you can replace `/` with the mount point of whichever partition you're interested in)

Comment: @DopeGhoti: I was thinking OP could also do something like `df -h | awk '$1 ~ "/dev/vda3"{print $4/1}'`  (for whatever filesystem they are concerned with).  Dividing the number by 1 will remove the % as well.  Of course the `date` pipelines could also be replaced with a single `date` command with the format OP wants

Comment: Both `df|tr` and `df|awk` are cleaner than `df|awk|sed|head|tail` (:

Comment: If your `else` clauses are indeed all just `else :`, the entire `else` clause can be omitted.

Comment: @Christopher: Neither will expand within single or double quotes.

Comment: There are at least three lines in there that will cause errors, preventing the script from running at all. shellcheck.net may find more. Go fix those first; or, if you have problems fixing the errors, please be more explicit about what your question is. Now it seems like you're just asking strangers on the internet to write a script for you.

Comment: If you are using `tar` to  handle files that old you really should consider using the `-p,--petrify` and `-r,--roseta` extensions to make sure they are both readable and intelligible for the duration of their service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should probably not quote strings that represent numbers that you're going to use in math equations. Think of them as numbers and make sure your code treats them that way.
2. Don't waste so much effort post-processing results when you could get the results you want in the right format in the first place.

   - `date +%F | sed 's/-//g'` should be just `date +%F%m%d`.
   - `date +%F | sed 's/-//g' | cut -c 1-4` should be just `date +%Y` (not the sed was not functional since you were cropping out just the first four characters anyway).
   - `df -h | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/%//g' | head -3 | tail -1` should be simplified several ways.

     - Don't mess with head/tail combos. You could have grepped for the line you want with the disk name, which would make this much less brittle in the event of say, adding a drive to the system.
     - You can just ask `df` for the info on one drive mount point anyway, so don't even bother with grep.
     - You can ask it for the number you want directly without sorting through a bunch of output fields
       A commenter gave you a way with `tr` and another with `awk`, here is one with `sed` that combines the two lines of output and removes everything that is not the number: `df --output=pcent / | sed 'N;s/[^[:digit:]]//g'`
3. Drop the `else :` construct. The `:` is a "noop" to fill in a required place for a command in the syntax of an else expression, but you aren't doing anything there so just don't use the else expression at all.
4. You were missing one `fi` to close you if structure.
5. This is a preference thing, but if you were more regular about your indentation and whether control structures were on the same line you wouldn't be so confused by syntax errors when they happen.
6. You have a variable assignment stuck in between an `if` and it's related `do`. It should be after it as it is part of the loop you are trying to run.
7. Don't call a variable with a name that's something it's not. If a variable is plural, give it a plural name. If it's a list of files, don't call it "dir". That sort of thing won't stop the code from running but it will make it hard to understand and debug, and you'll confuse yourself about what goes where.
8. Don't put shell glob patterns in a quoted variable. You should let those get expanded by the for loop. This will save you all kinds of grief with escaping file names that have odd things in them like quote marks.
9. Use bash's double bracket test syntax instead of the single brackets, they are much friendlier to things like empty strings.
10. When referencing bash variables, you must use the `$` prefix
11. Bash bath expressions should be in `$(( <expression> ))` syntax.

Taking all those notes into account, the script becomes something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

threshold=70
currentYear=$(date +%Y)
used=$(df --output=pcent / | sed 'N;s/[^[:digit:]]//g')

if [[ $used -ge $threshold ]]; then
    for FILE in ~/scripts/dailybackup/*.sheldns.*; do
        local fileYear=$((basename $FILE) | cut -c 1-4)
        if [[ $(($currentYear - $fileYear)) -gt 400 ]]; then
            echo "We are good to go"
        fi
    done
fi
```

There is lots more you could do to simplify this. For example you could skip the math and just ask for an old year date to start with: `oldDate=$(date +%Y -d '400 years ago'). This would give you a number that you could compare directly as in`[[ $fileYear -le $oldYear ]]`, making it just that much easier to see what's going on.

Also you probably could avoid the entire file iteration process by using file modification times rather than trying to parse their names:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(df --output=pcent / | tr -d "A-Za-z% \n") -ge 70 ]]; then
    find ~/scripts/dailybackup/ -type f -name '*.sheldns.*' -ctime +146000 -print
fi
```

Note when you are satisfied with the results you can change `-print` to `-delete` to just straight up delete the files it finds, but you'll also have to reduce 146000 (400 years in days) to something more likely to actually match some files.